# Setting up SOA for experimenting

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, soa, platform, bpel

I want to set up a SOA platform to demonstrate the key ingredients of it. Not knowing much about this topic, this seems to be an difficult task. I hope someone can clarify some points for me. I am aware that SOA has no exact definition, but I am trying to get some sense into it.

1. What are common platforms and development tools? Everything seems to have a little bit SOA in it, but I am searching for the big ones. Something like that?

   > - platforms: IBM WebSphere, SAP NetWeaver, RedHat Jboss SOA, HP SOA, systinet software, Microsoft .Net
   > - development tools: Eclipse SOA, NetBeans SOA, Visual Studio
2. What are the key ingredients of a SOA platform? I figured something like this:

   > Service Registry, Enterprise Service Bus, BPEL-Engine, Application Server

   Can I mix components from different platforms? I especially don't get the concept of the application server which every platform contains. Is it just an Java EE Environment?
3. I want to set up an environment for experimenting and demonstration. It should be based on some opensource SOA platform and developed with Eclipse SOA. I want to create a few services (with for example basic math operations), a Registry and a BPEL controlled process. What SOA System is suited best for me? Easy to learn, maybe good tutorials?

Any answer to any question would be awesome and be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1) & 2)
See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480021.aspx) and you may understand exactly what it is.

3) it will be a little hard unless you are extremely fast developer/deployer & configurator - I'm talking you work as fast as 10 people for a few months. Why not use existing examples ? Like Google for example

Comment: Theres a difference between a production environment and a experimental environment - setting up an basic experimental environment is usually possible for one person in a few days (or less) - depending on the specific platform and prior knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with Apache Axis/2 and Tomcat for you server environment.

And the splendid SOAPUI utility as your client. Moving on to real Java/C/perl/php/Python/C# or whatever clients as the server side develops more.

Don't bother with the heavyweight commercial servers like until you have a specific need for them as the installation and configuration is usually really tedious and most of their functionality is available from Apache.